# не могу получить графики frr, far

Tags: python

Вычисляю `frr, far` следующим образом:

```
far, frr, thresholds = metrics.roc_curve(label, preds, pos_label=2)
```

```
frr, far: (array([nan, nan, nan]), array([0.        , 0.33333333, 1.        ]))
```

Далее пытаюсь исправить `array([nan, nan, nan]` следующим образом:

```
d = far[~(numpy.isnan(far))]
```

Вместо `nan` получаю `array([], dtype=float64)`

Когда в конце вывожу все это, то получаю ошибку `x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (3,) and (0,)`

Если не исправляю `nan`, то получаю, что на рисунке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD:**
Код:

```
frr, far, threshold = metrics.roc_curve(scores, labels)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(threshold, far, 'r--', label='FAR')
ax.plot(threshold, frr, 'g--', label='FRR')
plt.xlabel('Threshold')
plt.plot(0.01,eer,'ro', label='EER') 


legend = ax.legend(loc='upper center', shadow=True, fontsize='x-large')

# Put a nicer background color on the legend.
legend.get_frame().set_facecolor('C0')

plt.show()
```

В scores, labels сейчас находится: `array([0., 0., 0., ..., 1., 0., 1.]), array([0., 0., 0., ..., 1., 0., 0.])`
В far, frr: `array([0.        , 0.20470224, 1.        ]), array([0.        , 0.94555177, 1.        ])`

В результате имею вот такой график, но он, как я понимаю совсем не правильный, в чем может быть проблема?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А покажите ка что у вас в `label` и `preds`. Меня терзают смутные сомнения, что там что-то странное.

Comment: labels, scores

(array([0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 0.]),    
 array([0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 0.]))

Comment: Если пишу ```frr, far, thresholds = metrics.roc_curve(labels, scores)```, то получаю ```(array([0., 0., 1.]), array([0., 1., 1.]))``` для ```frr, far```

Comment: А почему вы задали параметр pos_label=2, если у вас нет таких лейблов, у вас только 0 и 1?

Comment: когда применяю pos_label=1, получаю график в форме параболы

Comment: Ой, не форме параболы, а в форме параллелограмма

Comment: Так какая из меток означает позитивный результат, такую и пишите в pos_label. Если позитивная метка 1, то не надо вообще этот параметр задавать. И preds - это вероятности должны быть, а не готовые метки предсказаний, на значениях 0 и 1 вы не получите roc curve, только на вероятностях.

Comment: Не знаю как вы получаете предсказания, но вероятно вам нужно использовать не predict, а predict_proba

Comment: @CrazyElf Посмотрите, пожалуйста, UPD

Comment: Ну я воспроизвёл всё у себя - да, так это и должно выглядеть с вашими данными. Ещё раз повторяю, параметры для вычисления `roc_curve`: 1) истинные метки (нули и единицы) 2) **вероятности** или **степени уверенности** модели, с которой она предсказывает единицы, это числа из непрерывного диапазона [0,1], т.е. не просто 0 и 1, а всё что угодно 0.1, 0.123, 0.96 и т.д. Только из таких чисел можно построить `ROC` кривую. Она, кстати, обычно строится с `FPR` и `TPR` в качестве `x` и `y`, а `threshold` обычно не смотрят на таком графике.